# Is there any solution to download image from url which is javascript rendering

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

There are three images in this url. But it is loaded by the javascript like data:image/jpg. I need to wait for all three image to be loaded and download. Is there any solution to download the image from the url?

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.common.exceptions import StaleElementReferenceException
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", category=DeprecationWarning)

options = Options()
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
service = Service(executable_path = r'/usr/bin/chromedriver')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)
ignored_exceptions = (NoSuchElementException, StaleElementReferenceException)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20, ignored_exceptions=ignored_exceptions)
image_url = """https://nrex.quickbase.com/db/bpumk9kh3?a=dbpage&pageID=80&rid=169453"""
driver.get(str(image_url))
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@id='imageData']//a")))
driver.implicitly_wait(20)
data = driver.page_source
print(data)
```

Comment: Just take that `data:image/jpg...` string and base 64 decode the image data part of it.

Comment: @deceze How to wait for the all three to load without time.sleep

Comment: @deceze Or is there any solution other than selenium

Comment: That I don't really know, as I have little experience with Selenium in particular. I'd imagine you need the right `wait.until` and wait for the correct selector/test, but details of that may also depend on how exactly that pages creates those images.

Answer (score 1):

If the images are standard URLs, you can use a library like requests to download them. If they are base64 encoded, decode the base64 string to get the binary data of the image.

example:

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.common.exceptions import StaleElementReferenceException
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import warnings
import base64
import requests

warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", category=DeprecationWarning)

options = Options()
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
service = Service(executable_path='./chromedriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)
ignored_exceptions = (NoSuchElementException, StaleElementReferenceException)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20, ignored_exceptions=ignored_exceptions)
image_url = """https://nrex.quickbase.com/db/bpumk9kh3?a=dbpage&pageID=80&rid=169453"""
driver.get(str(image_url))
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@id='imageData']//a")))
driver.implicitly_wait(20)
data = driver.page_source

images = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//img")
for i, image in enumerate(images):
    src = image.get_attribute('src')

    if src and src.startswith('http'):
        response = requests.get(src)
        if response.status_code == 200:
            with open(f'image_{i}.jpg', 'wb') as file:
                file.write(response.content)
    elif src and src.startswith('data:image'):
        base64_encoded_data = src.split(',')[1]
        with open(f'image_{i}.jpg', 'wb') as file:
            file.write(base64.b64decode(base64_encoded_data))


driver.quit()
```

Comment: It is downloading only 2 images ""data:image "' has 3 images. I need to wait for the javascript to load

Comment: I need to take image from div[@id='imageData']

Comment: wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@id='imageData']//a"))) is waitting, js load img to html.

Comment: @touero If the first image is loaded it will go for the further process. It will no check whether all three image gets loaded

Comment: you can use `WebDriverWait(self.driver, timeout).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, '//div[@id='imageData']//a/img')))`, it will wait until all elements matching the specified XPATH appear on the page